# ramda js compose with find, pick with trim values

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, find, ramda.js

```
const obj = [
 {id: 1, name:'name1  ', age: 26, city: 'city1     '},
 {id: 2, name:'name2', age: 24, city: 'city2  '},
 {id: 3, name:'  name3', age: 28, city: '      city3  '},
 {id: 4, name:'name4  ', age: 25, city: 'city4  '}
]
```

i have function like

id might be 1,2,3,4...or..'All'

```
getData(id, obj) {
  if(id && id !=='All'){
    const res = obj.find((o) => o.id === id)
    return `${res.name.trim()} ${res.city.trim()}`
  } else if(id === 'All') {
    return 'All'
  }
  return ''
}

getData(1, obj) // name1 city1
getData('All', obj) // All
```

i have tried ramda js to convert the above code,

```
getData(id, obj) {
  return (id !== 'All') ? compose(R.find(R.propEq('id', id)))(obj) : 'All'
}
```

expected o/p is

```
getData(1, obj) => 'name1 city1'
getData('All', obj) => 'All'
getData('', obj) => ''
```

how to pick(name, city) and trim the values **using ramda**. any help

Comment: I would want to ask first whether you couldn't scrub your data up front, that is, use the result of `R.map(R.evolve({name: trim, city: trim}))(obj)` for further work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like the following

```
const getData = (id, obj) =>
  id == 'All' : 'All'                
  ? R.pipe(
      R.find(R.propEq('id', id)),    // {id: ..., name: '  foo', city: 'bar  '} | null
      R.ifElse(                      
        R.isNil,                     // if null
        () => '',                    // then ''
        R.pipe(                      // else
          R.props(['name', 'city']), // ['  foo', 'bar  ']
          R.map(R.trim)              // ['foo', 'bar']
          R.join(' ')                // 'foo bar'
        )
      )
    )(obj)
```

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it correct. Don't use `compose`:

```js
const getData = (id, xs) =>
    typeof id !== "number" ? id :
    R.find(R.propEq("id", id))(xs);
```

You can't compose a function with a list.